# Sending a message the first channel with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've seen a lot of bots that have a greeting message when they join. Its usually sent to the first channel of the server.

For example:

*bot joins the guild*

Bot: Hey! Thanks for inviting me!

The code i have right now is really simple:

```
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    the code goes here
});
```

I dont know how to send a message to a random (first) channel though.
If anyone could please tell me how the other bots do it I would be really greatful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: as of 9-27-2020, using Discord.js version 12.3.1, I only needed to add a reference to `cache` to get the correct channel and make sure the iteration was proceeding correctly.

I'm using Discord.js version 11.4.2, and I was able to use the following code to send a default message to the #general channel.  Replace `bot` below with whatever your `client`'s name is.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    let channelID;
    let channels = guild.channels.cache;

    channelLoop:
    for (let key in channels) {
        let c = channels[key];
        if (c[1].type === "text") {
            channelID = c[0];
            break channelLoop;
        }
    }

    let channel = guild.channels.cache.get(guild.systemChannelID || channelID);
    channel.send(`Thanks for inviting me into this server!`);
});
```

Edit: I've found that the `guild.systemChannelID` can be `null` so I've updated the code to search for the first text channel and use that for the initial message.

Comment: With the new edit, the sample code is syntactically incorrect for Javascript. The line with `channelLoop:` should be deleted, break should just be `break;`, and channel type and ID should be accessed via `c.id` and `c.type`.

Comment: It is not incorrect.  The `channelLoop:` is a label for `for` loops and is very handy, especially if you need to use nested `for` loops.  Using `c.id` and `c.type` would break this, because `guild.channels` is an array of arrays. The first index of each inner array is the channel id i.e. `c[0]` and the 2nd index is the information about that channel i.e. `c[1]`. So, no, it is not syntactically incorrect in the slightest.

Comment: My mistake regarding the labels, I honestly did not know such a thing existed. However, I do believe my latter part stands true. The `guildCreate` event passes in a `Guild` object, and `Guild#channels` is actually a `Collection` of `GuildChannel` objects (extended from `Channel`), not an array of arrays. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate | https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels | https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel

Answer (score 4):

I know is late but this is the way what I use and works for the 12.x version

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'text' && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
    channel.send("Thanks for invite me")
})
```

Comment: I don't know why but this just recently stopped working

Comment: @SkykidFelix Think is something about the intent update, guess have to check it out

Answer (score 3):

To be quite frank there is no "good way" todo this... There used to be until discord removed it. (used to be: `guild.defaultChannel`)
Now days bot devs do some tests to find out where they send the message...

There are multiple ways todo find a good channel (here's a few):

#### A: Find a channel called `welcome` or `general` whichever you prefer the bot to send it to.

```
guild.channels.find(`name`,`welcome`).send(`Thx for invite`);
```

#### B: Send to the first channel the bot is allowed to send to. (this works well unless bot is given admin);

```
guild.channels.sort(function(chan1,chan2){
    if(chan1.type!==`text`) return 1;
    if(!chan1.permissionsFor(guild.me).has(`SEND_MESSAGES`)) return -1;
    return chan1.position < chan2.position ? -1 : 1;
}).first().send(`Thx! for invite`);
```

The above code does this:

1. grab all the channels and lets sort them
2. if it's not a text channel `return -1`
3. if the bot is DIS-ALLOWED to send `return -1`
4. then sort the channels based on their position

#### C: Try other ways:

**Find a channel most members in the server can send to

Find a channel the role @everyone can send to `guild.roles.first()`

Find a channel that gets the most activity** (check for channel with most messages sent in the past 5-10 minutes)

Comment: Using the B method i get this error: "ReferenceError: message is not defined"

Comment: Oh I copied some code from a `message` event... forgot to convert it to `guildCreate` event..; Should be fixed... now

Comment: While running the fixed code i get this error: "TypeError: guild.channels.sort(...).first(...).send is not a function"

Comment: I just ran the code on my bot... And it works fine. I can only imagine `guild` isn't defined..
Are you putting the code in an `guildCreate` event? If so do you mind sharing the entire `guildCreate` event in a JS-Fiddle or something?

Comment: And/or It's possible it joined a server with no channels it's allowed to send to.

Answer (score 1):

What i was struggling with was to find get the guild. And also other codes weren't working for me.

So you need to find guild like this

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.first();
```

Then you want to get the first channel like this (probably only 'text channel', if not just remove the filter() )

```
const channel = guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'text').find(x => x.position === 0);
```

Then its all up to you what you want to do... I wanted to send a message to the channel for example, so i just did this

```
channel.send('Hello world');
```