# Sending a message into all servers where bot is

Tags: node.js, server, discord, discord.js, bots

How do I send one message per guild that my bot is in? It doesn't matter which channel it will be, but I don't know how to code it.

I finally came up with that idea:

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => { 
            const Embed = new discord.MessageEmbed();
            const Channels = guild.channels.cache.map(channel => `${channel.id} | ${channel.name}`).join(", ")
    
            Embed.setTitle(`Channels for ${guild.name}`);
            Embed.setDescription(Channels);
    
            message.channel.send(Embed); 
        });
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm working with commands handler so it has to be done with `module.exports`:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "informacja",
  aliases: [],
  description: "informacja",
  async execute(message) {
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => { 
            const Embed = new discord.MessageEmbed();
            const Channels = guild.channels.cache.map(channel => `${channel.id} | ${channel.name}`).join(", ")
    
            Embed.setTitle(`Channels for ${guild.name}`);
            Embed.setDescription(Channels);
    
            message.channel.send(Embed); 
        });
};
```

My code is not working at all

When I run it - nothing happens, no errors, no messages, just nothing.

tried to logged everything, but still nothing came up.

I also tried to log everything using `console.log()` but nothing is working

I remind: I need to send one message to all servers where my bot is, but only one channel

Comment: What is not working? Is nothing at all happening? Is there an error? Any unexpected behaviour?

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry, i will edit my post with error

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447954/sending-a-message-the-first-channel-with-discord-js/53286788) question, probably it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find a channel on each server where the client can send a message then send:

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.type === 'text' && c.permissionFor(client.user.id).has('SEND_MESSAGES')) 
    if(channel) channel.send('MSG')
       .then(() => console.log('Sent on ' + channel.name))
       .catch(console.error)
    else console.log('On guild ' + guild.name + ' I could not find a channel where I can type.')

})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple boilerplate to start with, you can later check channel with id, or smth like that

```js
client.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
    if(channel.type === 'text') channel.send('MSG').then('sent').catch(console.error)
})
```

Comment: but it wont send message to any text channel in whole servers?

Comment: it will send msg to all channels, that it has access to

Comment: i want to send only one message, not to all channels, but: only one channel -> one message per server

Answer (score -1):

## v13 code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const {
  MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  name: "send",
  description: "Send message to all guilds bot joined",
  usage: `!send <text>`,
  category: "dev",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => { 
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
    (c) => c.type === "GUILD_TEXT" && c.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")
  );
  channel.send('your_text')
})
}}
```

## v12 code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const {
  MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  name: "send",
  description: "Send message to all guilds bot joined",
  usage: `!send <text>`,
  category: "dev",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => { 
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
    (c) => c.type === "text" && c.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")
  );
  channel.send('your_text')
})
}}
```

Comment: do this also send message to every text channel in the guild?

Comment: @wolfie00 only first available channel per guild

Comment: okay, i'll try it out

Comment: it doesnt do anything, when i tried console.log outside the function, then it worked, but for now it isn't working. remember that im using module.exports for command handler so this has to seems be problem with that

Comment: @wolfie00 Weird, I just tested it on both versions and it works fine for me! So, if you add `console.log('something')` and execute your command it works, right?

Comment: can you send me the whole code with module.exports not just execute part?

Comment: @wolfie00 I edited my code but I still don't understand why it's not working for you! Are you sure you don't get any errors in console?

Comment: copied part of you code so my look like this now:

`module.exports = {

  name: "info",

  async execute (client, message, args) {

    client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => { 

    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(

        (c) => c.type === "text" && c.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")

      );
      channel.send('your_text')

    })
    }}
`
and now i have this error in console:
`client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => {
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
    at Object.execute (informacja.js:10:19)
`

Comment: altought, im using discord.js@12.5.3, btw can you send me you discord? i would be gratefull to solve this problem there

Comment: All you did was paste your existing code and provided no information on how it works or why you decided to use this algorithm. Why are you importing `fs`? Why are you using `map()` on the guild's collection instead of `forEach()` or `every()`? Your command structure is also not required for the OP's question. While it's quick and easy to just copy paste your existing code, it's best you create an minimal example suited to the question along with a description of how your answer works